# Tikz intersection of lines with unnamed points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, intersections

This works:

```
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A);
\draw (1,1) coordinate (B);
\draw (1,0) coordinate (C);
\draw (0,1) coordinate (D);
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);
```

but this doesn't:

```
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A);
\draw (1,1) coordinate (B);
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--B and (0,1)--(1,0));
```

I think it would be a great convenience to use points as in the second example, where they don't have to be named before being used as endpoints of lines.

Is there any way of coercing TiKZ to create intersections of lines given by endpoints, without naming those endpoints first?

Comment: An MWE would be nice. Not everyone will know how to turn this into something you can compile (or not).

Answer (score 4):

With `intersections` library you don't need to name each `coordinate` but each `path`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A);
\draw (1,1) coordinate (B);
\draw (1,0) coordinate (C);
\draw (0,1) coordinate (D);
\draw (A)--(B);\draw (C)--(D);  % added for `cross symbol` demonstration
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);

%

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]    % so that they won't overlap
\draw[name path=AB] (0,0)  -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=CD] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\draw [name intersections={of=AB and CD, by=x}] (x) circle (2pt)node[right] {$x$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt where the `(...)` in (1,0)--(0,1) is replaced by `{...}`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A);
\draw (1,1) coordinate (B);
\draw (1,0) coordinate (C);
\draw (0,1) coordinate (D);
\draw (A)--(B);\draw (C)--(D);  % added for `cross symbol` demonstration
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);

%

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]    % so that they won't overlap
\draw (0,0)  coordinate (A);
\draw (1,1)  coordinate (B);
%\draw (1,0) coordinate (C);
%\draw (0,1) coordinate (D);
\node (Y) at (intersection of A--B and {0,1}--{1,0}){Y}; % change coordinate to node for showing Y
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```