# Boxed text inside tcolorbox tcblisting?

Tags: listings, boxes, tcolorbox

I am writing a text which includes lots of programming snippets which I've put into environments which use tcolorbox/tcblisting:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\definecolor{vlgray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.7}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,fancyvrb}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings,breakable}

\newenvironment{shk}{%
  \tcblisting{listing only,colback=vlgray,colframe=vlgray,enlarge
  top by=0mm,top=-2mm,bottom=2mm,enhanced,
  after={\par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent},
  overlay={\node[draw,fill= black,yshift=4pt,xshift=-10pt,left,text=white,
         anchor=east,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] at (frame.south east)
         {Shakespeare};}, 
  listing options={basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,breaklines=true,
    language=HTML},}}
{\endtcblisting}
```

This means that in my document:

```
\begin{shk}
Now is the winter of our discontent
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
\end{shk}
```

looks like this:

[image]

which is exactly what I want.

However!  Suppose I want to box one word, say "winter", in my listing.  How do I do that?  I can't merely write `\fbox{winter}` as that will simply be listed, rather than escaped to LaTeX.  The `mathescape` option of the listings package doesn't seem to work in tcblisting.

I know I could use `tikzpicture` with `[remember picture,overlay]` to position a box on the page, but that seems a little inelegant... is there a way of boxing text within tcblisting itself?

Comment: Please, for your next question, would you mind to convert code snippets in a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1)? Several members in this community already suggested it in previous questions (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226613/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223957/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211237/1952, ...). So please, would you mind to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about `mathescape`, but presumably you don't want/need to enter math mode anyway, since you just want to make a box.

So use `escapechar=<char>` instead. I've turned your code snippets into an MWE to more clearly show the solution, but the same `escapechar=|` (or some other character not used anywhere in the listing) is equally valid inside `listing options` in your environment's definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily,escapechar=|}}
Now is the |\fbox{winter}| of our discontent
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the full code made into a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\definecolor{vlgray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.7}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}

\newenvironment{shk}{%
  \tcblisting{listing only,colback=vlgray,colframe=vlgray,enlarge
  top by=0mm,top=-2mm,bottom=2mm,enhanced,
  after={\par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent},
  overlay={\node[draw,fill= black,yshift=4pt,xshift=-10pt,left,text=white,
         anchor=east,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] at (frame.south east)
         {Shakespeare};}, 
  listing options={basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,breaklines=true,
    language=HTML,escapechar=|},}}
{\endtcblisting}


\begin{document}
\begin{shk}
Now is the |\fbox{winter}| of our discontent
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
\end{shk}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks indeed!  That's *exactly* what I was looking for.  I was hunting through the tcolorbox manual for information on escaping, and couldn't find anything - it must be in the documentation of the `listings` package instead.

Comment: Glad it helped you out, @Alasdair. You're right about needing to track down the `listings` documentation for all the available `listing options` settings. If I can answer anything else here, please let me know. Otherwise, please consider accepting my answer if you're happy with it. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Thanks again Paul, yes I've accepted your answer, and indeed implemented it in my LaTeX file.  And it works a treat!